# CSS filter - color blue but keep white white

Tags: html, css

I have an image of a floppy disk that I want to recolor blue whenever hovered. I was wondering if anyone knows how to apply a CSS filter like this to only color the already non-grey elements of the image?

Current CSS:

```
.saveIcon:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: grayscale(20%) brightness(70%) 
sepia(100%) hue-rotate(-180deg) saturate(300%) 
contrast(1);
}
```

Image (full-size):

[image]

Expected result(ish):
[image]

Comment: share the image also

Comment: That´s done now! :)

Comment: Oh, dear, I just realized the image doesn´t have white in it.. I guess that makes my whole question defunct, unless there´s a way to make it apply to all grayscale shades?

Comment: can you edit your question with the expected result (edit the image with Gimp/paint to show what you want)

Comment: Also fixed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple [`hue-rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate) will do it. Simply adjust the degree to obtain the color you want:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

img:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(40deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P1q3.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hue-rotate()` and `grayscale()` combination to get same color

```css
   
.saveIcon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter:hue-rotate(40deg) grayscale(30%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P1q3.png" class="saveIcon" width="200">
```